# Highlighting Leaflet map items when using Marker Cluster plugin

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm using Leaflet together with Marker Cluster plugin on AngularJS app.

When selecting on a map's item I need to highlight it. Because I'm using divIcons, I'm adding or removing class, also setting colour if item is not a marker.

For that I'm saving last clicked item in the memory so that when the next item is selected, I can de-highlight the previous item and highlight current one.

```
        // De-highlight previous item
        if (lastClickedLayer) {
            if (lastClickedLayer instanceof L.Marker) {
                lastClickedLayer._icon.classList.remove('marker-highlighted');
            }
            else {
                lastClickedLayer.setStyle({
                    color: (lastClickedLayer.feature.status === 'active') ? '#43A7E0' : '#EB7938'
                });
            }
        }

        // Highlight item on the map
        lastClickedLayer = e.layer;

        if (e.layer instanceof L.Marker) {
            e.layer._icon.classList.add('marker-highlighted');
        }
        else {
            e.layer.setStyle({
                color: '#32C9AC'
            });
        }
```

Everything would be fine if not Marker Clustering! When I zoom out and get a cluster of current markers (let's say I select one marker first) and then zoom in back to that cluster, my selected marker does not have assigned 'marker-highlighted' class.

Also, If I'm at the vey end of zoom-in and clusters are showing spider-webs of markers (or how they're called), when cluster in which is selected marker is closed, I can't seem to unset class of that layer - it's just gets undefined.

How could I possible solve my issues?

Oh and my map items are kept as a new L.MarkerClusterGroup().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the marker from the cluster when it's selected ...

```
markerCluster.removeLayer(selectedMarker);
map.addLayer(selectedMarker);
```

and put it back to the cluster when it deselected ...

```
map.removeLayer(selectedMarker);
markerCluster.addLayer(selectedMarker);
```

You can see an example [here](http://franceimage.github.io/leaflet/13/) that shows single selection

Each time you create a marker, you add this click handler ...

```
        m.on('click', function(e) {
            if(selectedMarker != false) {
                map.removeLayer(selectedMarker);
                markerCluster.addLayer(selectedMarker);
                selectedMarker.setIcon(unselectedIcon);
                if(selectedMarker == e.target) {
                    console.log('clear selection');
                    selectedMarker = false;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('change selection');
                    selectedMarker = e.target;
                    selectedMarker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
                    markerCluster.removeLayer(selectedMarker);
                    map.addLayer(selectedMarker);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('new selection');
                selectedMarker = e.target;
                selectedMarker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
                markerCluster.removeLayer(selectedMarker);
                map.addLayer(selectedMarker);
            }
        });
```

However, I can see 2 downsides:

1. You have to use another event if you want a popup
2. The movements of the markers when they are retrieved from or added to the cluster may disturb the user

Comment: Your approach seems to be OK but there's one BUT. When I add selected marker to map layer, I need to modify it a bit (change colour). So at first save selected marker to the memory. But apparently when I put it back to the cluster, somehow it has that changed colour also. Maybe you know how would be possible to copy (clone, duplicate) that marker/feature/sublayer that I could save original copy in the memory, and when removing modified one, I could put original one back to the cluster?

Comment: Did you follow the link to my example. When you click on a marker it becomes black, when you click on it again or if you click another marker it becomes red again and goes back to the cluster.

Comment: Well it's set the icon (or in my case colour) every time on add and remove. But isn't there a way of saving original state of the marker and change the marker only when it's selected but when deselected to revert it back to original saved in the memory marker? In this case it used just two types of markers - active and inactive. But I have different types of markers, with different colours).

Comment: I see what you mean. When you create your marker, you can add 2 properties (marker.selectedIcon and marker.unselectedIcon) where you reference the proper icons. You just have to write: selectedMarker.setIcon(selectedMarker.selectedIcon). Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: I've followed your approach and styling layer each time when selecting and deselecting. That's the only one way which was working properly. Thanks, I will accept your answer.